# Error using if statement when concatonating strings and $_server values to variable

Tags: php

```
$stuff = "<tr><td>" . if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "</td>";
```

I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in`

Sorry I am a newb.

Comment: You can't concatenate (`.`) process control structures like that ,although you _could_ use the ternary operator: `'string'.(test?'treustring':'falsestring').'string'`

Comment: Thank you everyone, makes sense. will mark an answer when i can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an `if` statement inside a variable definition. Use ternary operator instead:

```
$stuff = "<tr><td>" . (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '' ) . "</td>";
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] = '';
}
$stuff = "<tr><td>" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "</td>";
```

Using the ternary operator allows you to compact multiple lines of code into one, at the expense of some readability. In this case, using ternary operator makes sense. See the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 1):

Use a ternary operator:

```
$stuff = "<tr><td>" . (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : "") . "</td>";
```

Comment: Aka "the conditional operator"

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `if` *operator*. It looks like this: `a ? b : c`, and will produce `b` if `a` is true, or `c` otherwise.

```
$stuff = "<tr><td>" . (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '') . "</td>";
```

As you can see, it can be used inline with other operators. It is also often called the "ternary" operator, but that is the same as calling `+` a "binary" operator (`?:` just happens to be the only ternary operator in common use).

Answer (score 1):

this is not a good coding style
use this:

```
$stuff = "<tr><td>";
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
{
 $stuff .= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
$stuff .= "</td>";
```

Comment: I mean what user1166981 wrote, not mine ;)

Comment: Whether it's good coding style or not depends on the context. Sometimes using inline if is more readable (especially if you have a fallback for the else branch)